# Process builder: prevent same action from happening twice on update

Tags: process-builder, email-alert

I have a Process Builder flow built out where I send a notification email when an opportunity is created and specific fields are filled out. The email fires under the "Immediate Actions" section, then there's a number of timed actions that occur afterward.

There's different action groups depending on the value of a field, and what I've noticed is that if that field is modified after being saved, it re-runs the flow and will sometimes trigger the same Immediate Action email alert.

I'd like to avoid this "Immediate Action" email from being sent repeatedly, though I do want the opportunity to change the action group it's in when updates are made. Is this possible?

Here's a look at the flow...

[image]

So if you imagine that the opportunity is created and the field in question equals "Sunday" it will go into the first action group. But, if it's changed later to "Thursday" it will re-run and hit the second action group. Both times the "Immediate Actions" will fire and thus the same email will be sent twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Delete the immediate actions from the current process (email)
2. Create an additional process (or WFR) that fires only when an opportunity is created to send an email

Comment: Hi Matt, did my answer make sense? Did you manage to get this to work correctly?

Comment: sorry -- it does indeed make sense. I think I'll have to tweak that concept a bit but it sounds like it will work. Thanks!